# CSS selector for first td in each column that is not empty

Tags: jquery, css, css-selectors

Is there any selector that for each columns selects only the first cell which is not empty, i.e. cells containing 2, 3, and 4 from the code example below?

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td><span class='a'>2</span></td>
      <td><span class='a'>3</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span class='a'>4</span></td>
      <td><span class='a'>5</span></td>
      <td><span class='a'>6</span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

My current solution has multiple selectors with fixed column numbers, which is not ideal on tables with many columns.

```
$('table tr td:nth-child(1) .a').first()
$('table tr td:nth-child(2) .a').first()
$('table tr td:nth-child(3) .a').first()
```

Comment: Not sure if I understood your question well. I answered too early. You want to select the elements which are first child of the row and which are not empty right?

Comment: First not empty should be 2 and 4, why 3?

Comment: I will try a different formulation; If columns go from left to right and rows go from top to bottom, I want to select only one cell from each column, and if there are multiple rows in like in the example, I want to select the one closest to the top row, i.e. 5 and 6 should not be selected since they are 'below' 2 and 3

Comment: It isn't possible to do that with pure CSS, as there is no parents selector. You'll have to use JS.

Comment: I get it, you want to select first non empty element in each column but I don't think that is possible with pure CSS because the elements don't belong to the same parent (siblings).

Comment: @nevermind, for each column (column 2 contains td's with 2 and 5), not for each row/tr

Comment: @Skogen you can always add some class to the required elements and then style that class.

Comment: @Vucko, just did exactly that, but as I already use .map() on the row array and populate each td with handlebars {{#each}}, I didnt see any other solution than to reiterate the table with a separate function designated only to add classes - It feels rather ugly :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way HTML tables are structured, there is no way in terms of CSS for a cell to know it is the nth cell in its column that matches or doesn't match a condition.

Ideally you would need something similar to `:nth-child(An+B of sel)`, but for cells in a column (or for *rows*, depending on how you see it), since each cell element is a child of a row element and so `:nth-child()` won't be of any use. However `:nth-column()`, also from selectors-4, works rather differently. Furthermore, columns are an abstraction and so they don't match selectors anyway — only elements do.

Someone in the comments mentioned the lack of a parent selector being the reason why this isn't possible. Personally I'd like to see how they might accomplish this with such a feature, because I just don't see how it is even relevant to your problem. You're not trying to match the parent of a cell, a row, the `tbody`, the table, or whatever. You're trying to match cells, *relative to their columns*, not their parents/rows (something that the column combinator does but still not for your specific scenario). In fact, what I just said above explains precisely why this argument makes no sense.

The best you can do is to just count the number of columns in your table and loop through the cells finding the first ones in each column that are not empty. If the number of columns can vary, or you just don't want to hardcode everything, you will have to build your selectors programmatically (assuming you do end up using selectors somehow — there are a number of ways to approach this problem programmatically, but the point is just that: you *have* to do it programmatically).

Answer (score 2):

If you know how many columns your table will have, then you might be able to achieve this. It won't be pretty, but you can do it.

- Start by selecting the first cell: `td:first-child`
- ... but only if not empty: `td:first-child:not(:empty)`
- Now, select the second one if not empty: `td:nth-child(2):not(:empty)`
- ...but only if the first was empty: `td:first-child:empty+td:not(:empty)`
- And the third if not empty, but only if the first two were empty: `td:first-child:empty+td:empty+td:not(:empty)`
- ...and repeat with a new `+td:empty` for as many columns as you are likely to have leading empty cells.
- Then join all these selectors together with commas to form a multiple selector:

  ```
  td:first-child:not(:empty),
  td:first-child:empty+td:not(:empty),
  td:first-child:empty+td:empty+td:not(:empty),
  td:first-child:empty+td:empty+td:empty+td:not(:empty) {
      /* styles go here */
  }
  ```

As I said, it really isn't pretty CSS. It ought to do what you're asking for, but I wouldn't want to have to maintain code that looks like that.

The idea also falls down somewhat if you don't know in advance how many empty cells your table could have, as you need to write CSS to support the largest possible number of them.

So to be honest, my recommendation if at all possible would be to modify your HTML code to put a class name into the elements you want to select. It's a much cleaner solution.

Comment: Unfortunately, on closer inspection this does not account for non-empty cells following the first non-empty cell. You can see this even with the markup given in the question: http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/y7p3rvLj

Answer (score 0):

If you combine the Jquery [Not](https://api.jquery.com/not/) selector with the [Empty](http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/),
You can select all td elements that are not empty.

First i iterate over all TR elements.
Find all td elements that are not empty.
Then color the first td element that is not empty.

```js
$('tr').each(function() {
  var $elem = $(this).find('td').not(":empty").first();
  $elem.css('background-color', "red");
});
```

```css
td {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td><span class='a'>2</span>
      </td>
      <td><span class='a'>3</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span class='a'>4</span>
      </td>
      <td><span class='a'>5</span>
      </td>
      <td><span class='a'>6</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: First not empty should be 2 and 4, why 3? –  @nevermind  <- I'm jumping on this and hope I'm right XD